# Showing Data Viz (i.e. D3.JS,etc.) on Actions on Google

Tags: google-visualization, data-visualization, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is there a way to output a chart or other data visualizations in Actions on Google?

example:

User: "What is the percentage of sales this december?" 
Actions: *outputs a chart generated using d3js or other data viz tools*

The only workaround that I can think of is by saving the chart as images then use that image to show in basic card. but the image is too small, it's not visually pleasing to use in other devices i.e. Google Home Hub.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is generate an image and send it as a [basic card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card). There's not another way to visually show information.